# Convert Factor to Date/Time in R

Tags: r, date, posixct, r-factor, posixlt

This is the information contained within my dataframe:

```
## minuteofday: factor w/ 89501 levels "2013-06-01 08:07:00",...
## dDdt: num 7.8564 2.318 ...
## minutes: POSIXlt, format: NA NA NA
```

I need to convert the minute of day column to a date/time format:

```
minuteave$minutes <- as.POSIXlt(as.character(minuteave$minuteofday), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I've tried `as.POSIXlt`, `as.POSIXct` and `as.Date`. None of which worked. Does anyone have ANY thoughts.

The goal is to plot minutes vs. dDdt, but it won't let me plot in the specified time period that I want to as a factor. I have no idea what to try next...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to insert an `as.character()` before parsing as a Datetime or Date.

A factor will always come back first as a number corresponding to its level.

You can save the conversion from factor to character by telling `read.csv()` etc to no store as a factor:  `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.  You can also set that as a global option.

Once you have it as character, make sure you *match the format string to your data*:

```
R> as.POSIXct("2013-06-01 08:07:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2013-06-01 08:07:00 CDT"
R>
```

Note the `%Y-%m-%d` I used, as opposed to your `%m/%d/%y`.

*Edit on 3 Jan 2016:* This is now much easier thanks to the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package which automagically converts from many types, including `factor`, and does so *without requiring a format string*.

```
R> as.factor("2013-06-01 08:07:00")
[1] 2013-06-01 08:07:00
Levels: 2013-06-01 08:07:00
R> 
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime(as.factor("2013-06-01 08:07:00"))
[1] "2013-06-01 08:07:00 CDT"
R> 
R> class(anytime(as.factor("2013-06-01 08:07:00")))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
R>
```

As you can see we just feed the factor variable into `anytime()` and out comes the desired POSIXct type.

Comment: I think he already inserted the `as.character` the problem is that he has an error in the format imo

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that too on second read and expanded my answer.  The remaining problem (which your answer repeats) is the `as.POSIXlt` conversion (without extracting minutes).

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
library(lubridate)
minuteave$minutes <- ymd_hms(minuteave$minutes)
```

this will return minuteave$minutes as a POSIXct object.

Hope this helps you.