# Convert factor to date object R without NA

Tags: r, date, time-series

**Question:** how can I convert a `factor` to a `date` object without getting `NA` values.

Here's a similar post: [Convert Factor to Date/Time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348992/convert-factor-to-date-time-in-r)

In that post, the user converted to a `character` object before a `date`. I am getting `NA` values when converting to `character` object using `as.character` inside the `as.Date` function.

I have a column in the dataframe with the date in factor format with different numbers of occurrences. Here's the information contained in the data.frame.

```
> head(fraud, 5)
  TRANSACTION.DATE TRANSACTION.AMOUNT AIR.TRAVEL.DATE POSTING.DATE
1 2/27/14                  25.00                 <NA>          2/28/14
2 2/28/14                  25.00                 <NA>          2/28/14
3 2/27/14                  25.00                 <NA>          2/28/14
4 2/27/14                  20.00              2/27/14          2/28/14
5 2/27/14                  12.13                 <NA>          2/28/14

> str(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE)
 Factor w/ 519 levels "1/1/14","1/1/15",..: 228 230 228 228 228 230 226 228 230 228 ...

> summary(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, 5)
9/30/14 9/17/14 11/4/14 9/23/14 (Other) 
    197     187     171     160   19221
```

Converting the factor to a `date` object resulted in `NA` values.

```
> fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE <- as.Date(as.character(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE), 
+                                       format = "%m/%d/%Y")
> head(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, 5)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

Checking if the `as.character` function worked.

```
> fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE <- as.character(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE)
> head(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

**EDIT: I used as.Date function but got the wrong formatting**

```
> fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE <- as.Date(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
> str(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE)
 Date[1:19936], format: "0014-02-27" "0014-02-28" "0014-02-27" "0014-02-27" "0014-02-27" ...
> head(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, 5)
[1] "0014-02-27" "0014-02-28" "0014-02-27" "0014-02-27" "0014-02-27"
```

**EDIT 2: Here's the dput value**

```
> dput(droplevels(head(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE)))
structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2/27/14", "2/28/14"
), class = "factor")
```

**Solution: using %y instead of %Y**

```
> fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE <- as.Date(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, "%m/%d/%y")
> head(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, 5)
[1] "2014-02-27" "2014-02-28" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27"
```

Comment: You are using `$d` instead of `%d` .  Also `as.Date` will be enough i.e. as.character may not be needed. i.e. `as.Date(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE, '%m/%d/%y')
#[1] "2014-02-27" "2014-02-28" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27"`

Comment: I had seen your edit, but using the data copied from your post, I am not getting any NAs.  It may be better if you use `dput` to show the data for reproducibility.

Comment: I performed the edit, but still got NA values when using the as.Date function without as.character. I fixed the syntax as well. Is there anyway I give another view of my data? It seems that I am not providing a good enough reproducible example.

Comment: a dput output may be more reproducible. i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(fraud)))`

Comment: I think one needs `as.character` as otherwise the numeric values of the factor are used, i.e., `1:nlevels(fraud$TRANSACTION.DATE)`. Yet, I do not understand why `as.character` isn't working as desired.

Comment: Probably, you can also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566875/as-date-returning-na-in-r)

Comment: @BenjaminHofner  I did try with `factor` column and it worked well without converting to `character`.  I am using R 3.2.1

Comment: @akrun: True. Nice move of the `as.Date` function.

Comment: I made another edit, the as.Date function worked and converted the factor to a date object. The mistake earlier was not reloaded the dataset before applying as.Date. Now, the only problem is the formatting for date.

Comment: @ScottDavis I am not sure how you are getting different date value.

Comment: @akrun I put another edit with the dput value. Does that help?

Comment: It is working fine for me.  If v1 is the object.  `as.Date(v1, '%m/%d/%y')#
[1] "2014-02-27" "2014-02-28" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27"
[6] "2014-02-28"`  It must be related to something in the `setlocale` as in the link

Comment: There is something odd here. Please provide the output suggest by @akrun plus `str(fraud)`. I can't reproduce the  problem with the Dates returning `NA`s with the same dates as you showed.

Comment: @BenjaminHofner You don't need `as.character()` as there is an S3 method for class `"factor"` which effectively calls `as.Date(as.character(x))` for you.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I am not getting the NA values anymore after akrun's suggestion. Now, I am getting a different format for the dates than "2014-02-27".

Comment: @ScottDavis To format the dates (R will use the YYYY-MM-DD for *display*) look at `strftime()` for details. Note however that you want to keep it as a `"Date"` object and only format when needed for plotting or in tables that you output.

Comment: Change to using `%y` instead of `%Y` and you should be OK. What happens with `%Y` when you don't have year with century seems OS dependent. I see something different on Linux (Fedora 22) for example. Adding longer answer now.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, you are saying now that I have it in a date object, I can change the format to YYYY-MM-DD ? Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: @ScottDavis Normally yes, but your problem is that you are still using the wrong format placeholders. See my answer or previous comment: You want a lowercase `%y`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem now is that your format string states the dates include the year *with century* where your dates only contain the year *without century*. You need to use the `%y` placeholder, not the `%Y` one.

```
dates <- factor(c("2/27/14","2/28/14","2/27/14","2/27/14","2/27/14"))
as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%y") # correct lowercase y
as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y") # incorrect uppercase y

> as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "2014-02-27" "2014-02-28" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27" "2014-02-27"
> as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "14-02-27" "14-02-28" "14-02-27" "14-02-27" "14-02-27"
```

Notice R gets it right when you use the correct placeholder; lowercase **y**.

What happens with `%Y` when you don't have a year with century seems OS dependent. As you can see on Linux (Fedora 22) I get no padding of the year part whereas you are seeing zero-padding.