# R: Incorrect Dates After Using read.csv

Tags: r

This has me stumped. I have tried several solutions that I've found elsewhere on SO and other places to no avail. The closest one to my problem appears to be this question:

[Convert factor to date object R without NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681434/convert-factor-to-date-object-r-without-na)

I'm trying to read in a .csv that has date information. The column with the dates in it reads in as a factor. When I convert it to the "date" class, the dates get garbled. Below is a Dropbox link to a simple .csv file that should allow you to reproduce the problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/07xuuy6pmw3qctt/dates.csv?dl=0

Code:

```
dates <- read.csv("dates.csv")


dates
        Name      Date
1   Person 1  1/1/2000
2   Person 2  2/1/2001
3   Person 3  3/1/2002
4   Person 4  4/1/2003
5   Person 5  5/1/2004
6   Person 6  6/1/2005
7   Person 7  7/1/2006
8   Person 8  8/1/2007
9   Person 9  9/1/2008
10 Person 10 10/1/2009



dates$Date <- as.Date(dates$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
dates

dates
        Name       Date
1   Person 1 2020-01-01
2   Person 2 2020-02-01
3   Person 3 2020-03-01
4   Person 4 2020-04-01
5   Person 5 2020-05-01
6   Person 6 2020-06-01
7   Person 7 2020-07-01
8   Person 8 2020-08-01
9   Person 9 2020-09-01
10 Person 10 2020-10-01
```

All of the years get changed to 2020, when they should start with 2001 and end with 2009. How can I get the dates to display as dates without the values being changed incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, I get the same result.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `read.csv`. You are just using `as.Date` incorrectly. Please read carefully `?strptime` first. I don't know what comes  first in your data- the day or the month, but you definitely should change `%y` to `%Y`. As a side note, it's quite silly to accuse a single function after  running a whole code chunk without checking what each step does.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the raw values you are trying to convert to date?

Comment: @LloydChristmas, edited to show how the values print right after reading in.

Comment: To add to the fair points above, you might also want to let RStudio take *some* of the strain. In the latest version, click *Import Dataset* on the *Environment* tab, select the csv option and follow the GUI.

Comment: In other words `as.Date(date$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")` or  `as.Date(date$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")` (depends if the month or the day comes first)

Comment: The format is mdy, but I get the same result regardless of whether I use %y or %Y. The year gets garbled to 2020.

Comment: `as.Date(factor(c("1/1/2000", "2/1/2001")), "%m/%d/%Y")` works just fine for me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I got it to work just now. I had to start from the beginning for it to work properly. Thanks. I'd tried changing this before I posted and it didn't work, but I think I was making the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
dbName <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s//07xuuy6pmw3qctt/dates.csv” #your file
```

To read as `data.frame`:

```
df <- read.csv(dbName,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format ='%m/%d/%Y' )
head(df)
        Name       Date
1   Person 1 2000-01-01
2   Person 2 2001-02-01
3   Person 3 2002-03-01
4   Person 4 2003-04-01
5   Person 5 2004-05-01
6   Person 6 2005-06-01
```

To import the file as `xts`-object:

```
dbFile <- as.xts(read.zoo(dbName,sep=',',header=TRUE,index.column = 2,format='%m/%d/%Y',stringsAsFactors=F))
names(dbFile) <- "name"

head(dbFile)
           name       
2000-01-01 "Person 1" 
2001-02-01 "Person 2" 
2002-03-01 "Person 3" 
2003-04-01 "Person 4" 
2004-05-01 "Person 5" 
2005-06-01 "Person 6"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! The critical thing that I'd been missing is that once you use 'format ='%m/%d/%y' in error, you have to go back to square one for 'format ='%m/%d/%Y' to work.